# How do I access .htaccess in Bitnami (Apache)?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, bitnami

I was wondering what the file path for my Bitnami Apache server for the `.htaccess` file.

I tried to find the answer online, but none of the answers I have looked at seem to be correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bitnami Engineer here,

.htaccess files are disabled by default in the Bitnami solutions. You can modify the AllowOverride parameter in the Apache's configuration files inside the /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf and /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/vhosts/ folders to enable them. However, we suggest you create a htaccess.conf file with the content of the .htaccess files and include in your app's conf file inside the /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/vhosts/ folder. You can learn more about it here:

https://docs.bitnami.com/general/infrastructure/lamp/administration/use-htaccess/

Comment: Thanks! I'll lake a look into it.